# Using a PHP while loop causes my CSS footer to disappear

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP `while` loop to get data from a MySQL database and repeat some `<div>`s per the data. When the data is retrieved, the issue is that the footer disappears, because the background image becomes unlimited.

Below is the CSS code for background and footer.

```
.wrapper {
    background: url(../images/bg.png) #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 30px 0;

.footer {
    color: #999;
    padding: 40px 0px 0px 15px;     
}
```

Comment: You should be using capitalization and punctuation in your questions.  It shows an effort that will be returned by the person answering.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand your question when you do not post much of code. Or even complete code snippets.

Check out `background-repeat` [Read more about this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response
the issue that when the  while loop get data from database the page will be expands and the footer disappear

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on what @Appallan advised,

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
    background: url(../images/bg.png) #eee no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 30px 0;
}
```